# Button inaccessible because of jQuery parallax plugin

Tags: jquery, parallax

I use a jQuery parallax plugin and my button "Découvrez-la" is inaccessible because of the use of different layers on a .scene

[labonneboite.fr](http://labonneboite.fr)

[Parallax plugin](http://matthew.wagerfield.com/parallax/)

How can I fix it please ? I tried to use z-index and that didn't work

```
<ul id="content-laboite" class="scene midcenter">
                <li class="layer" data-depth="0.50">
                    <img class="tin" src="images/laboite.png" alt="Visuel de la boite">
                </li>
                <li class="layer tiny-hidden" data-depth="0.90">
                    <p class="slogan fst-sentence fliptext">0% d'additif</p>
                    <p class="slogan snd-sentence fliptext" data-delay="800">100% créatif</p>
                    <p class="pursuit">labonneboite crée vos sites internet sur mesure</p>
                    <button class="more">Découvrez-la !</button>
                </li>
                <li class="layer" data-depth="0.90">
                    <a href="#" id="open-sidebar"><div class="news-frame"><div class="news-qmark txtcenter">?</div></div></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

Comment: you could set the button position as fixed, z-index 30 (or anything above any other layers.

Comment: Thank you but I tried this solution, that didn't work :-(

Comment: @Xroad I suppose you can't reorder the layer? If you can, just put the layer with the button as the last child.

Comment: Thank you for the idea ! I put the button on the same layer that my other button and that's works perfectly !

Answer (score 0):

Put that button outside from scene but in your first page container(with relative or absolute position) and set style attr `position:absolute;` and center it on the page with f.e.: `bottom:10%;left:48%;`(style attr) somewhere where it won't be colliding with your background.
Anyway who likes to chase buttons around ?

Comment: Good idea but the button will have no parallax effect

Comment: Imho, using parralax on buttons is overkill, imagine that you want to click on a button and the button is moving away. It may cause unforeseen problems on exotic resolutions.